# Country Code Prefix UI Objective C when key in phone number

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, uitextfield

How do I create the following User Interface? I currently have a mutable array with all the country codes. I'd like to create like a lined `UITextField`? And how to insert `>` in the `UITextField` and load a new page to display the country code. And when clicked will return back to the `UITextField` Please share some thoughts, your help is gladly appreciated

[image: Pic]

Comment: You can set delegate to your `CountryListViewController` and can pass dataDictionary to previous view controller. Share your implemented code you did so far..

Comment: I haven't started implementing my code, is the Country (Germany with a > ) a `UITextField`? The prefix +1 is also a `UITextField`? I assume the phone number is a `UITextField`. When clicked on the Country how to pass a segue to is it a new VC with `UITableView`? Clicking on the Country how to pass back to the previous `UITextField`?

Comment: share your country table data...please

Comment: It will also be a mutable array which is [USA, +1, GERMANY, +62, MALAYSIA, +60, SINGAPORE, +65]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest to use a UIButton instead of UITextField and then add that > as the image of the UIButton